# Will Samsung laptops be fully (OOTB) supported by Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, power-management, support, samsung

Power management like: suspend, hibernate, open/close LID, optimal ("healthy") disc activity, internal modem, backlight control, FN keys etc. Will it be fully supported by Ubuntu out of the box? So the average user could just use the laptop not worrying about it? I know there's Voria's PPA but that should be OOTB support.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need OOTB support? There is nothing wrong with using Voria tools.

Comment: You can find details on Linux-compatibility for Samsung laptops on this site: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search_computer&computer_vendor=Samsung&computer_type=notebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Samsung laptops, just with other manufacturers' machines, use wildly different components from one model to another. It's impossible to say that they'll all just work.

Googling the model number is usually a good starting point for finding users with problems but even if you don't find issues, it doesn't mean you won't have them.

If you can find a list of the specifications you can check the individual components (graphics, wireless, etc) for issues which might exist in different laptops with these parts, again, with Google.

And there is [the Ubuntu Certified Hardware page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) for which manufacturers can submit their laptops for testing. The problem specifically for you is Samsung don't submit their computers for testing. If you're buying many, *many* machines, perhaps you have enough power to convince somebody at Samsung to join the certification program.

Comment: he is right. It's more important that the individual components are all compatible